# How to use template-based elements in Polymer 2/3?

Tags: polymer, custom-element, polymer-3.x

Certain elements, like `iron-list`, require `template` elements as children.
However, [Polymer 3 strips `template`s of its content](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#preserve-template-contents).

How are these seemingly conflicting principles supposed to work together?
See the jsbin examples @ https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-list (they don't work due to the empty nested template).

The `preserve-content` leads to missing binding capability, so that's no viable solution.
What's the reason for this `template`-stripping anyways? (Docs just say "better performance".)

Comment: Tested in Chrome 69.0.3497.100 x64 and Firefox 62.0.3 x64 with Polymer 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

The given examples have been updated and work now.

It seems like the combination of v3 elements and v2 polymer-core caused the failure.

Also my personal guess is that `template`-based elements are manually [`Templatizer`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/448093b6dcd7bc26629d3e314613bf83cdc252b0/lib/legacy/templatizer-behavior.js)-ing their child `template`s to stamp the content of the `template` even though the `template`'s actual `content` is `undefined`.
`Templatizer` seems to access the cache `content` that is noted in the docs.